# Can I use UniMRCP to stream audio to a websocket from a live call sent over FreeSWITCH?

Tags: websocket, voice, freeswitch, unimrcp

We use FreeSWITCH to send voice calls. We are already integrated with UniMRCP to do speech recognition with Google Speech. For this particular use case, we need to stream audio live from both legs of a call and send to a websocket. I am wondering whether we can use uniMRCP for this purpose, or if another FreeSWITCH plugin is more suitable.